# How to determine the opengl version under windows?

Tags: opengl

I knew Windows comes with Opengl drivers. If I also have NVidia driver, how to termine the OpenGL version?

Comment: As Reed says, also fyi ::glGetString(GL_VENDOR), ::glGetString(GL_RENDERER);

Answer (score 4):

> I knew Windows comes with Opengl drivers.

Actually it doesn't. Windows comes with a OpenGL emulation. But actual OpenGL drivers are only available through the vendor original drivers.

> how to termine the OpenGL version?

Create a OpenGL context and use the `glGetString` function to retrieve the identifying values. Of most interest are GL_VERSION and GL_RENDERER.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`glGetString(GL_VERSION)`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlGetString) to retrieve the currently executing OpenGL Version.

Comment: You might want to mention that this routine will work only after OpenGL context has been created.

Comment: @SigTerm Yes - it requires a valid context - either one to be created, or `wglMakeCurrent` to make an existing one current.